# C# Программное создание потоков

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Как создать определенное количество потоков при помощи кода?
Пробовал так, но программа зависает и работает медленнее, чем если объявлять потоки вручную.

```
   var threads = new List<Thread>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
            {

                threads.Add(new Thread(() => Parsing(url,abc+Abc)));
i++;
            }
            threads.ForEach(t => t.Start());
            threads.ForEach(t => t.Join());

        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190949/create-multiple-threads-and-wait-all-of-them-to-complete

Answer (score 0):

> программа зависает

Метод `Join` блокирует основной поток программы до того момента, когда работа дочернего потока будет завершена.

Если Вам не требуется в обязательном порядке дождаться завершения работы дочерних потоков, не используйте его.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так.

```
public async Task StartTasks()
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 0; i < someNumber; i++)
    {
        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            //code
        });
        tasks.Add(t);
        //что-бы не зависло
        Task.Delay(5).Wait();
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```